# How to get min and max date for month?

Tags: java, date, calendar

[image]
From above image...
For calendar view, Every month includes 42 dates. It includes previous month and next month dates also.

How to get first and last date for given month as per above image which will includes next and previous dates for month.

Ex. In above image Month is Feb 2019...but first date is 27 Jan and last date is March 9.

How to find these dates using Java 8 Calendar class or any?

Comment: How are these dates stored?

Comment: By the way: how did you come up with the 42 in your question, there are clearly NOT 42 days between 27th jan and 2nd march. On the left side there 42 but until 9th march, on the right / center there are 35 (one week less).

Comment: Oops..typo mistake..9th march..updated

Comment: If by *Calendar* you meant `java.util.Calendar`, don’t use that class. It is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1):

1. Take the weekday of the first day of the month. Then you know how many days to include before that. In your picture the Feb 1st is a Friday. There are 5 days before Friday in a week (if your week starts on Sunday). So you include the last 5 days of January.
2. Same for end of month. In your picture Feb 27th is a Thursday, so you need the 2 first days of March.

Comment: If we follow 1st step for Feb 2021 then it will not work..as it includes extra one week

Comment: Since Feb 1st 2021 is a Monday it would only include 1 day before which is Jan 31st.

Comment: The question specifically says it wants 42 days, which means that the last day of the month may not be in the last row printed, as illustrated in the image in the question. So item 2 is wrong, though that is how you would do it, if the number of rows to print should be dynamic, instead of a static 6 rows = 42 days.

Comment: @Andreas You are right. but then you would just add 7 more days, or just take the first day and add 42 days...

Answer (score 1):

Do it like here https://www.baeldung.com/java-between-dates:

```
public static List<LocalDate> getDatesBetweenUsingJava8(
            LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate) {

        long numOfDaysBetween = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate);
        return IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1)
                .limit(numOfDaysBetween)
                .mapToObj(i -> startDate.plusDays(i))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

and then to print all dates:

```
System.out.println(getDatesBetweenUsingJava8(LocalDate.now(), LocalDate.now().plusDays(42)));
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the first date of the calendar, you need to get the nearest first-day-of-week (Sunday or Monday) that is on or before the first-day-of-month for the given calendar month (year+month).

To specify the calendar month, use the [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class.

To identify the first-day-of-week, use the [`WeekFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html) class.

To locate the day-of-week on or before a given date, use the [`TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#previousOrSame-java.time.DayOfWeek-) method.

Together, that means:

```java
DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek = WeekFields.of(locale).getFirstDayOfWeek();
LocalDate firstDate = yearMonth.atDay(1)
                               .with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(firstDayOfWeek));
```

Since you show 42 days in the calendar, i.e. always 6 weeks, the last date is easy enough:

```java
LocalDate lastDate = firstDate.plusDays(41);
```

If you instead want to show only as many weeks as necessary, calculate similar to how first date was calculated:

```java
DayOfWeek lastDayOfWeek = firstDayOfWeek.minus(1);
LocalDate lastDate = yearMonth.atEndOfMonth()
                              .with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(lastDayOfWeek));
```

---

To see this in effect, lets print the calendar. Printing a full calendar is fairly easy, though slightly complicated if you want to print in a given language, since we'd then have to auto-adjust the calendar width, but it can be done like this:

```java
static void printCalendar(YearMonth yearMonth, Locale locale) {
    // Determine calendar first and last dates
    DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek = WeekFields.of(locale).getFirstDayOfWeek();
    LocalDate firstDate = yearMonth.atDay(1).with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(firstDayOfWeek));
    LocalDate lastDate = firstDate.plusDays(41);
    
    // Calculate column width
    int width = Stream.of(DayOfWeek.values())
                      .mapToInt(d -> d.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, locale).length())
                      .max().getAsInt();
    
    // Print title (month year)
    String title = yearMonth.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM uuuu", locale));
    System.out.printf("%" + ((3 + width) * 7 + 1 - title.length()) / 2 + "s%s%n", "", title);
    
    // Print day names
    for (int days = 0; days < 7; days++)
        System.out.printf("| %" + width + "s ", firstDayOfWeek.plus(days).getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, locale));
    System.out.println("|");
    
    // Print date numbers
    for (LocalDate date = firstDate; date.compareTo(lastDate) <= 0; ) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++, date = date.plusDays(1))
            System.out.printf("| %" + width + "d ", date.getDayOfMonth());
        System.out.println("|");
    }
}
```

*Test*

```java
printCalendar(YearMonth.of(2019, Month.FEBRUARY), Locale.US);
printCalendar(YearMonth.of(2019, Month.FEBRUARY), Locale.FRANCE);
```

*Output*

```
               February 2019
| Sun | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat |
|  27 |  28 |  29 |  30 |  31 |   1 |   2 |
|   3 |   4 |   5 |   6 |   7 |   8 |   9 |
|  10 |  11 |  12 |  13 |  14 |  15 |  16 |
|  17 |  18 |  19 |  20 |  21 |  22 |  23 |
|  24 |  25 |  26 |  27 |  28 |   1 |   2 |
|   3 |   4 |   5 |   6 |   7 |   8 |   9 |
```

```
                   février 2019
| lun. | mar. | mer. | jeu. | ven. | sam. | dim. |
|   28 |   29 |   30 |   31 |    1 |    2 |    3 |
|    4 |    5 |    6 |    7 |    8 |    9 |   10 |
|   11 |   12 |   13 |   14 |   15 |   16 |   17 |
|   18 |   19 |   20 |   21 |   22 |   23 |   24 |
|   25 |   26 |   27 |   28 |    1 |    2 |    3 |
|    4 |    5 |    6 |    7 |    8 |    9 |   10 |
```

Notice how the US version starts on Sunday, and the French version starts on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

**This is my sample solution for question...I tested multiple cases..working right.. can anyone tell me if this will work or not? if not then why?**

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(2021, 5, 1);

    if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 1) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);
    } else {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1 - calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
    }

    System.out.println("First Date of Month :: " + calendar.get(Calendar.DATE));

    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 41);

    System.out.println("Last Date of Month :: " + calendar.get(Calendar.DATE));
```